# Selenium to click this button

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to create a test to select this button

[image]

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn--stretch btn--primary btn--green t-auth__login--btn">
                Create my account</button>
```

the code that I used is this, but it doesn't work

```
driver.findElement(By.className("btn btn--stretch btn--primary btn--green t-auth__login--btn")).click();
```

Can somebody tell me the correct way to code this test?

If it is any help, the webpage in question is https://www.dunnesstores.com/customer/login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `click()` on the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.btn.btn--stretch.btn--primary.btn--green.t-auth__login--btn")).click();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn--stretch btn--primary btn--green t-auth__login--btn' and contains(., 'Create my account')]")).click();
  ```

---

Ideally to `click()` on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.btn.btn--stretch.btn--primary.btn--green.t-auth__login--btn"))).click();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn--stretch btn--primary btn--green t-auth__login--btn' and contains(., 'Create my account')]"))).click();
  ```